# SimpleCrypto.encrypt not working galaxy s4 i.e. jelly Bean

Tags: android

my application is not working in galaxy s4 i.e. on jelly bean. 
I am just simply saving my some data into database using the `SimpleCrypto.encrypt` method.

And let i am trying to retrieve this data using `SimepleCrypto.decrypt` method. but i am
not getting data and it print null.

can anybody help me why this issue is coming to me. as it working fine on s2 and s3 but on
s4 it is not working as expected.

```
public long insertEntry(DeviceInfo _myObject) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_NAME, _myObject.getName());
    contentValues.put(KEY_ADDR, _myObject.getAddr());
    try {
        contentValues.put(KEY_ADMINPASSWD, SimpleCrypto.encrypt(SecuRemote.masterpassword,_myObject.getAdminPasswd()));
        contentValues.put(KEY_BTPIN, SimpleCrypto.encrypt(SecuRemote.masterpassword,_myObject.getBtPin()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    String alias = _myObject.getAlias();
    if((alias == null) || (alias.equals(""))) {
        alias = _myObject.getName();
    }       
    contentValues.put(KEY_ALIAS, alias);
    String type = _myObject.getType();
    if(type == null) {
        type = "";
    }       
    contentValues.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
    //SecuRemote.LOG("DEBUG: added device entry: " + _myObject.toString());
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
}
```

to retrieve the data i am using below method that will decrypt the data from database.

```
public DeviceInfo getEntry(String addr) 
{
        if(SecuRemote.superDebug) SecuRemote.LOG( "DeviceInfo getEntry(" + addr + ")");

    DeviceInfo rec = new DeviceInfo();

Cursor cursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE,new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_ADDR, KEY_ADMINPASSWD, KEY_BTPIN, KEY_ALIAS, KEY_TYPE},KEY_ADDR + "= '" + addr + "'",null, null, null, null, null);

        if((cursor.getCount() == 0) || !cursor.moveToFirst()) 
               {        
            SecuRemote.LOG( "No device record found for addr: " + addr);
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }

        rec.setName((cursor.getString(NAME_COLUMN)));
        try {
            rec.setAdminPasswd(SimpleCrypto.decrypt(SecuRemote.masterpassword, new String(cursor.getString(ADMINPASSWD_COLUMN))));
            rec.setBtPin(SimpleCrypto.decrypt(SecuRemote.masterpassword, new String(cursor.getString(BTPIN_COLUMN))));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            SecuRemote.LOG("Error decrypting device secret passwords");
        }
        rec.setAddr((cursor.getString(ADDR_COLUMN)));
        rec.setVersion(SecuRemote.getPreference("version_"+rec.getAddr(), context));
        rec.setAlias((cursor.getString(ALIAS_COLUMN)));
        rec.setType((cursor.getString(TYPE_COLUMN)));
        SecuRemote.LOG("Record found");
        cursor.close();
        return rec;
    }
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, S4 running Jelly Bean